# Прекращение работы программы

Tags: c++

Вот этот код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>

#include <string.h>

using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char *s = "eeee eee .";
    char t[99], *sa[20];
    int c, n = 0;
    sa[n] = strtok_s(t, " ,.\n", NULL);
    while (sa[n])
        sa[++n] = strtok_s(NULL, " ,.\n", NULL);

    for (c = 0; c < n; ++c)
        printf("%s\n", sa[c]);

    return 0;
}
```

прекращает работу программы. Никак не могу исправить. В чем ошибка?

Среда — MS Visual C++ 2012.

Comment: Возможно потому, что s - это литерал, который располагается в статическом хранилище, и изменять его нельзя. Сделайте его не char*, а char[]

Comment: Все равно прекращает работу.
char s[] = "eeee eee .";
        char t[99], *sa[20];
  int c, n = 0;
  sa[n] = strtok_s(s, " ,.\n", NULL);
  while (sa[n]) {
                sa[++n] = strtok_s(NULL, " ,.\n", NULL);
        }
  for (c = 0; c < n; ++c) printf("%s\n", sa[c]);
        return 0;

Comment: Вообще третий аргумент должен быть не NULL, а строка.

Comment: выдает ошибку. уже все перепробовал. такая же ошибка. копирую код с сайта, запускаю у себя - не работает. В чем ошибка и близко не знаю

Answer (score 3):

[[@Артур352](/users/14734/%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80352)](/users/14734/%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80352), я думаю ошибка в том, что третий аргумент должен быть **адресом указателя**, а у Вас NULL.

Я пишу в Linux-е, тут вместо виндовой `strtok_s()` есть аналогичная функция `strtok_r()`.

Вот пример с ней.

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ cat strtok.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char *token, *saveptr, 
    *str = av[1] ? *(++av) : (char *)"xaxa xoxo xixi", 
    *strd = strdup(str);
  const char *sep = av[1] ? av[1] : " ";

  int i = 0;
  str = strd;
  printf ("source: [%s] separators: [%s]\n", str, sep);
  while (token = strtok_r(str, sep, &saveptr)) {
    printf ("token[%d] : <%s>\n", i++, token);
    str = 0;
  }

  free(strd);
  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ strtok.c
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
source: [xaxa xoxo xixi] separators: [ ]
token[0] : <xaxa>
token[1] : <xoxo>
token[2] : <xixi>
End
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out "  zqwe 223 , sy, ,sa,so ,   ," ", "
source: [  zqwe 223 , sy, ,sa,so ,   ,] separators: [, ]
token[0] : <zqwe>
token[1] : <223>
token[2] : <sy>
token[3] : <sa>
token[4] : <so>
End
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ echo $?
0
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

Что непонятно, спрашивайте